# Convert String to date using Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework and face a problem of mismatching types in database with my models.

Specifically I have `String` field Date in class and `date` in SQL Server database. Due to that I have an error about improper type when loading data into model.

I attached some of my code, were I suppose casting can be applied.

```
public class MovementMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Movement>
{
    public MovementMap()
    {
        ToTable("viewMovement", "met");
        HasKey(e => e.IdMovement);
        Property(r => r.DateMovement).HasColumnName("dateMovement"); 
        //Type of DateMovement - String, but column dateMovement in db has type date.
    }
}
```

How can I convert it when loading or whenever? 
Would be glad to receive any ideas!

Comment: My recommendation is that you change the type in your class to a `DateTime` if you can.  If not, check out `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: I try not to change the model now. Can you suggest where exactly should I use parsing?

Comment: tbh - the minimal pain in changing to a DateTime column now will FAR outweigh the neglect further down the road- the old adage `horses for courses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `Column` attribute to your `DateMovement` property in the class. This will tell Entity Framework that the database value is a `Date`:

```
[Column(TypeName="Date")]
public string DateMovement { get; set; }
```

That being said, I would recommend changing the `DateMovement` property to be a `DateTime` for consistency.

If you don't want to change the model, you can perform this configuration by adding a `HasColumnType` call to your code sample:

```
public class MovementMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Movement>
{
    public MovementMap()
    {
        ToTable("viewMovement", "met");
        HasKey(e => e.IdMovement);
        Property(r => r.DateMovement).HasColumnName("dateMovement").HasColumnType("Date"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll change type of the property and I'm absolutely agree with you. But I was really intrested in solving this problem another way - if i couldn't change the model.